# How can i get a value to class from another class

Tags: java, android, swing, android-studio

[Original code is here NotificationUtils.java](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-2/)

I want to get a value of roomid method from  activeroom.java. i think i can use getClass().getMethod() . ?
So, This code is in NotficationUtils.java and try to get a string value  of "isRoomId" method from ActivityRooms.java

```
    public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context,String chatRoomId) {
            boolean isInBackground = true;
            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
                List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
                for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                    if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                        for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                            if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
```

next to if (),   i am defining m method and i wanna get a value "isRoomId"  methods from "active class.

```
                              try {
                                    Method m = activeProcess.getClass().getMethod("isRoomId",null);

                                    if (chatRoomId.equals(m.toString()))
                                    {
                                        isInBackground = false;

                                    }
                                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
```

ActivityRoom.java  has got isRoomId Method.

```
 public static String chatRoomId;
   chatRoomId = intent.getStringExtra("chat_room_id");

        public static String isRoomId()
                {

                    return chatRoomId;
                }
```

Comment: Just make `isRoomId()` static and call `ActivityRoom.isRoomId()` whenever you need it.

Comment: if i make isRoomId() as static method.  can i use like that .. Method m = activeProcess.getClass().getMethod("isRoomId",null);

Comment: Yes, you can use it just like that. Check out redflar3's answer for more explanation.

Comment: no. i am trying it but . it is not working.  everytime isInBackground return as false   .........................isInBackground = false;

Comment: Just use `ActivityRoom.isRoomId()`

Comment: how can i use ActivityRoom.isRoomId() in notificationUtils.java. i have to call activeProcess.getClass().getMethod("isRoomId",null);  ??? is it ?

Comment: Ohh. thanks man. i used directly ActivityRoom.isRoomId()  it is working.

Answer (score 1):

`isRoomId()` method of class `ActiveRoom` is not a static method. Hence you need to instantiate the class and then invoke the method of that object.

If the value returned by `isRoomId` is independent of the object state of the class `ActiveRoom`, then you can make this a static method like below. Then you can invoke this method from your `NotficationUtils.java`

Method

```
public static String isRoomId()
{
    String chatRoomId="6";        
    return chatRoomId;
}
```

Invokation

```
ActiveRoom.isRoomId()
```

If the logic that you plan to write in isRoomId() is depended on the object state, then you need to get the relevant object reference in your NotificationUtil class and invoke the method on that object.

Comment: if i make isRoomId() as static method.  can i use like that .. Method m = activeProcess.getClass().getMethod("isRoomId",null);

Comment: you can just use `ActiveRoom.isRoomId()`

Comment: `getMethod()` is part of reflection api. if at all you have to use it, `getMethod()` will return an object of type `Method`. Then you have to `invoke()` the method with the required parameters. IMO that is complicated for your use case.

Comment: thanks. redflar. pls could you see updated to ActivityRoom.java in question.. i made public static . NotificationUtils  always return false.

Comment: how can i use ActivityRoom.isRoomId() in notificationUtils.java. i have to call activeProcess.getClass().getMethod("isRoomId",null); ??? is it ?

Comment: `activeProcess` is an object of type `String`. `activeProcess.getClass()` will return an object of type `Class` for the class `String`. calling `getMethod()` on a Class object will return the an object of type `Method` which corresponding to the method which you asked for. However the  `String` class is not having a method called `isRoomId()`. Hence you code will throw `NoSuchMethodException`..   However you can invoke the code like  `String value = ActiveRoom.isRoomId()`.. Let's say This will create a variable named `value` which will store the value returned by your static method `isRoomId()

Comment: Ohh. thanks man. i used directly ActivityRoom.isRoomId()  it is working.